# button click to set an optionsCaption value as default in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am currently working on options binding in knockout, the bindings is doing everything for me as per my requirement. But currently the problem I am facing is

> how to set optionsCaption Value again to my Select Box on a button
>   click.

Here is my code

```
 var clickMe = function(){
//Do Something 
    alert("I am working");
    //Want to enable optionsCaption Value again as current value in select box
};
var operator = ko.observable();
var vm = 
 {
     operators : [
{id: 0, name: 'addition'},
{id: 1, name: 'subtraction'},
{id: 2, name: 'division'},
{id: 3, name: 'multiplication'}
   ],
 operator:operator,
 clickMe: clickMe
}
 ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Html

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.operators, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.operator, optionsCaption: 'Select Text'"></select>
<button data-bind="click: clickMe">Enable Caption</button>
```

Please answer by editing my fiddler.
[Fiddler Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishraaj13/zv33h5kw/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set back your `operator` property to `null` or `undefined` to get back the `optionsCaption` value in your select:

```
var clickMe = function(){
//Do Something 
    alert("I am working");  
    vm.operator(undefined);
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wb03zL0c/).

Comment: `vm.operator('')` and `vm.operator(null)` will also work.

Comment: thanks guys, I did it by using `this.operator(undefined)`. it wasn't hard but its done